# In Selenium , Calling passed Test in new test

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Let's agree that I have one test case to login and this test is passed , so what I wanna do is to call this passed test in another test ..
More explanation :
let's assume that I have 2 functions " login and logout " , I check my login function and my tests are passed , then I wanna test my logout function so what I'm trying to do is calling the passed login test in the logout test so when I run the second test it will be easy to check if the first test is passed then check the second test .

So What I did make the driver opened twice then the second test is failed.  so how can I do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you can return value (boolean) in first function if its failed or if its successfully passed and after you must use this boolean in the second function.

Best way is to use @afterMethod and getting resuld boolean of first test:

```
    public class paymentsPageDirectDebits{
    Boolean results = false;

    @AfterMethod
    public void GettingResultOfTheLastTestCase(ITestResult result){

        if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE)
        {
            results = false;  

        } else if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP)
        {
            test.skip("Test Case Has Been Skipped");
        } else
        {
            results = true;
            test.pass("Test Case Passed");
        }

        closing.closeBrowserAndClearCookies();
    }

    @Test(alwaysRun=true)
    public boolean FirstsFunction()
    {
    

        //Your logic of first test case here!


    }

    @Test(alwaysRun=true)
    public voidSecondFunction()
    {
        if(results == true){
            System.out.println("There must be logic for second function is 
            first is successed")
        }
    
    }
```

so in the afterMethod function you are checking the result value of the last test case and if its True (successful) you continue to execute your logic code in the second test case!